# Explaination of InsertionSort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have the following Insertsort where numbers are distinct

```
InsertionSort(A[1,...., n])
1  for i from 2 to n do
2      for j from 1 to i - 1 do
3          if A[i ] <= A[j ] then
4              tmp <- A[i ]
5              for k from i downto j + 1 do
6                  A[k] <- A[k - 1]
7              A[j ] <-  tmp
```

my question is why is it bad if condition in line 3 will returns true for more than one j? and is it possible that this line will be true for at most one j?

Comment: It can be true for more than one j. Based on dataset..

Answer (score 0):

Let us first align the code.

```
InsertionSort(A[1,...., n])

1  for i from 2 to n do
2    for j from 1 to i - 1 do
3       if A[i] <= A[j] then
4          tmp <- A[i]
5          for k from i downto j + 1 do
6              A[k] <- A[k - 1]
7          A[j] <-  tmp
```

To answer your question (given - array of A of distinct numbers)

```
why is it bad if condition in line 3 will returns true for more than one j?
```

Line 3 is the place, where we identify the position to insert the selected element in sorted order.
For every such find  we do shift of all the elements 1 step to right side.
Hence, it is always bad for more true in line 3.

Now, for the question

```
is it possible that this line will be true for at most one j?
```

Yes, with distinct elements you will never get situation with condition true more than once.
Because every time we run the inner for loop (line 2) on an existing sorted array.

If we found place and shifted array elements, the last element (A[i]) is always greater than rest of elements before it.
Hence, line 3 will be true at most once.

**Note:**

This algorithm can be further optimzed to run in O(n) for nearly soted arrays with a different [implementation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/)

Hope it helps!